# Where does an object's toString method get its value from?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, prototype

I'm writing some custom classes in JavaScript and I would like their `toString` method to return a value that reflects the class itself rather than the Object class. For example:

```
function MyClass(){}

var my_object=new MyClass();
alert(my_object);// Returns "[object Object]"
```

If I instantiate an HTMLImageElement the result is different:

```
var my_image=new Image();
alert(my_image);// Returns "[object HTMLImageElement]"
```

I can override the toString method for my custom class like this:

```
MyClass.prototype={
    toString:function(){
        return "[object MyClass]";
    }
};
```

Overriding the `toString` method allows me to get a result that reflects my class name, but I feel like this approach is not the same one used by the HTMLImageElement. Is it? Is there a way to change the result of `toString` without overriding it in the prototype? Are built in classes like HTMLImageElement actually JavaScript objects or are they something else?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Read http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2 and http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2. Those "class" names are only supposed to be used for host objects, for everything that is plain JS (such as your `MyClass`) the value "Object" is appropriate.

Comment: If you want to override the _toString_ method for each "class", you should do it with a "class helper" that creates constructors and hooks up their prototype chain automatically. This is worth doing if you're going to have a lot of "classes" in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use...

```js
function MyClass(){}
var my_object = new MyClass();
```

... `my_object.toString` is inherited from `Object.prototype`:

```js
my_object.hasOwnProperty('toString');                      // false
MyClass.prototype.hasOwnProperty('toString');              // false
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('toString');               // true
/* => */ my_object.toString === Object.prototype.toString; // true
```

In the case of `Image` instances, they inherit `toString` from `Object.prototype` too:

```js
var my_image = new Image();
my_image.hasOwnProperty('toString');                      // false
HTMLImageElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('toString');    // false
HTMLElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty('toString');         // false
Node.prototype.hasOwnProperty('toString');                // false
EventTarget.prototype.hasOwnProperty('toString');         // false
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('toString');              // true
/* => */ my_image.toString === Object.prototype.toString; // true
```

`Object.prototype.toString` is defined as

> **[15.2.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2) Object.prototype.toString ( )**
>
> When the `toString` method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If the `this` value is `undefined`, return `"[object Undefined]"`.
> 2. If the `this` value is `null`, return `"[object Null]"`.
> 3. Let `O` be the result of calling [`ToObject`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9) passing the `this` value as the argument.
> 4. Let `class` be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of `O`.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings `"[object "`, `class`, and `"]"`.

The difference is that the internal [[Class]] of `my_object` is `"Object"`, but the internal [[Class]] of `my_image` is `"HTMLImageElement"`.

Therefore,

- No, `HTMLImageElement` do not produce a custom string by overriding `Object.prototype.toString`, they use a custom [[Class]] instead.
- But you can't use the same approach, at least in ECMAScript 5:

  > **[8.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) Object Internal Properties and Methods**
  >
  > This specification defines no ECMAScript language operators or
  >   built-in functions that permit a program to modify an object’s
  >   [[Class]] or [[Prototype]] internal properties

Comment: That's what I was wondering. I guess I'll just have to stick with overriding the prototype method if I want more descriptive toString methods. Thanks!